# Can a Sequence Diagram realistically capture your logic in the same depth as code?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, uml, modeling

I use UML Sequence Diagrams all the time, and am familiar with the UML2 notation.

But I only ever use them to capture the essence of what I intend to do. In other words the diagram always exists at a level of abstraction above the actual code. Every time I use them to try and describe **exactly** what I intend to do I end up using so much horizontal space and so many alt/loop frames that its not worth the effort.

So it may be possible in theory but has anyone every really used the diagram in this level of detail? If so can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem but when I realize that I am going low-level I re-read this:

> You should use **sequence diagrams**
>   when you want to look at the behavior
>   of several objects within a single use
>   case. Sequence diagrams are good at
>   showing collaborations among the
>   objects; they are not so good at
>   precise definition of the behavior.
>
> If you want to look at the behavior of
>   a single object across many use cases,
>   use a **state diagram**. If you want
>   to look at behavior across many use
>   cases or many threads, consider an
>   **activity diagram**.
>
> If you want to explore multiple
>   alternative interactions quickly, you
>   may be better off with **CRC cards**,
>   as that avoids a lot of drawing and
>   erasing. It’s often handy to have a
>   CRC card session to explore design
>   alternatives and then use sequence
>   diagrams to capture any interactions
>   that you want to refer to later.
>
> [*excerpt from Martin Fowler's [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) book*]

Answer (score 4):

It's all relative. The law of diminishing returns always applies when making a diagram. I think it's good to show the interaction between objects (objectA initializes objectB and calls method foo on it). But it's not practical to show the internals of a function. In that regard, a sequence diagram is not practical to capture the logic at the same depth as code. I would argue for intricate logic, you'd want to use a flowchart.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two issues to consider.

### Be concrete

Sequence diagrams are at their best when they are used to convey to a single concrete scenario (of a use case for example).

When you use them to depict more than one scenario, usually to show what happens in every possible path through a use case, they get complicated very quickly.

Since source code is just like a use case in this regard (i.e. a general description instead of a specific one), sequence diagrams aren't a good fit.  Imagine expanding x levels of the call graph of some method and showing all that information on a single diagram, including all if & loop conditions..

That's why 'capturing the essence' as you put it, is so important.

Ideally a sequence diagram fits on a single A4/Letter page, anything larger makes the diagram unwieldy. Perhaps as a rule of thumb, limit the number of objects to 6-10 and the number of calls to 10-25.

### Focus on communication

Sequence diagrams are meant to highlight communication, not internal processing.

They're very expressive when it comes to specifying the communication that happens (involved parties, asynchronous, synchronous, immediate, delayed, signal, call, etc.) but not when it comes to internal processing (only actions really)

Also, although you can use variables it's far from perfect. The objects at the top are, well, objects. You could consider them as variables (i.e. use their names as variables) but it just isn't very convenient.

For example, try depicting the traversal of a linked list where you need to keep tabs on an element and its predecessor with a sequence diagram. You could use two 'variable' objects called 'current' and 'previous' and add the necessary actions to make current=current.next and previous=current but the result is just awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have used sequence diagrams only as a description of general interaction between different objects, i.e. as a quick "temporal interaction sketch". When I tried to get more in depth, all quickly started to be confused...

I've found that the best compromise is a "simplified" sequence diagram followed by a clear but in depth description of the logic underneath.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no - it does capture it better then your source code!
At least in some aspects. Let me elaborate.

You - like the majority of the programmers, including me - think in source code lines. But the software end product - let's call it the System - is much more than that. It only exists in the mind of your team members. In better cases it also exists on paper or in other documented forms.

There are plenty of standard 'views' to describe the System. Like UML Class diagrams, UML activity diagrams etc. Each diagram shows the System from another point of view. You have static views, dynamic views, but in an architectural/software document you don't have to stop there. You can present nonstandard views in your own words, e.g. deployment view, performance view, usability view, company-values view, boss's favourite things view etc. 
Each view captures and documents certain properties of the System.

It's very important to realize that the source code is just one view. The most important though because it's needed to generate a computer program. But it doesn't contain every piece of information of your System, nor explicitly nor implicitly. (E.g. the shared data between program modules, what are only connected via offline user activity. No trace in the source). It's just a static view which helps very little to understand your processes, the runtime dynamics of your living-breathing program.

A classic example of the Observer pattern. Especially if it used heavily, you'll hardly understand the System mechanis from the source code. That's why you use Sequence diagrams in that case. It captures the 'dynamic logic' of your system a lot better than your source code.

But if you meant some kind of business logic in great detail, you are better off with plain text/source code/pseudocode etc. You don't have to use UML diagrams just because they are the standard. You can use usecase modeling without drawing usecase diagrams. Always choose the view what's the best for you and for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**U.M.L. diagrams are guidelines, not strictly rules.**

You **don't have to make them exactly & detailed as the source code**, but, you may try it, if you want it.

Sometimes, its possible to do it, sometimes, its not possible, because of the detail or complexity of systems, or don't have the time or details to do it.

Cheers.

P.D.
Any cheese-burguer or tuna-fish-burguer for the cat ?